# Adding line plot with boxplot

Tags: r, line, scatter-plot, boxplot

Sample data

```
set.seed(123)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))

dat <- data.frame(years = rep(1980:2014, each = 8), x = sample(1000:2000, 35*8 ,replace = T))
boxplot(dat$x ~ dat$year, ylim = c(500, 4000))
```

I have another dataset that has a single value for some selected years

```
ref.dat <- data.frame(years = c(1991:1995, 2001:2008), x = sample(1000:2000, 13, replace = T))
plot(ref.dat$years, ref.dat$x, type = "b")
```

[image]

How can I add the line plot on top of the boxplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ggplot2 you could do this:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = years, y = x)) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = dat,  aes(group = years)) + 
  geom_line(data = ref.dat, colour = "red") + 
  geom_point(data = ref.dat, colour = "red", shape = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(500, 4000)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I get this error `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake Try it again, please.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to figure out the x-axis on the boxplot. You have 35 boxes and they are plotted at the x-coordinates 1, 2, 3, ..., 35   - i.e.  year - 1979. With that, you can add the line with `lines` as usual.

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(years = rep(1980:2014, each = 8), 
    x = sample(1000:2000, 35*8 ,replace = T))
boxplot(dat$x ~ dat$year, ylim = c(500, 2500)) 

ref.dat <- data.frame(years = c(1991:1995, 2001:2008), 
    x = sample(1000:2000, 13, replace = T))
lines(ref.dat$years-1979, ref.dat$x, type = "b", pch=20)
```

[image: Line over boxplot]

The points were a bit hard to see, so I changed the point style 20.  Also,   I used a smaller range on the y-axis to leave less blank space.